# Writing pretty & consistent multiline-conditions?

Tags: ruby

For a better readability i normally prefer writing multiline-conditions in `if`-statements as follows:

```
if
  something == nice and
  anotherthing == bad
then
  do_something
  and_so_on
end
```

I am currently facing `while`-loops (at a point where i can't avoid them) and have to use multiple conditions. I tried the following and got a corresponding `syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block (SyntaxError)`:

```
while
  something == nice and
  anotherthing == bad
do
  do_something
  and_so_on
end
```

It turned out that the optional `do`-keyword can't stand alone in the next line, in opposite to the `then`-keyword. This is how it works -- after putting the `do` at the end of the preceding line:

```
while
  something == nice and
  anotherthing == bad do

  do_something
  and_so_on
end
```

For my comprehension of readability, this is probably not as readable as the corresponding `if`-statement, which "enforces" a newline and accentuates the indentation (again).

Did i miss an alternative syntax and/or is it probably a flaw in Ruby's syntax-design (shouldn't it be possible to put the `do` into the next line)?

Comment: Why not just remove `do` or replace `do` with `(` and insert `)` as the penultimate line? Frankly, I can't understand why you'd want to add unnecessary code for a questionable improvement in readability.

Comment: My intention is not to add unnecessary code - i'm trying to find a way to write things more consistent. Which helps at least me to read code faster and at this case i wondered why i'm not able to put the `do` into a different line like the `then`-keyword for an `if`-statement.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: after reading your comment i realized that i probably did ask the slightly wrong question. I edited my question for that reason - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `begin end while` syntax, Your conditions will be at the end of the statement but as the `if` statement:

```
begin
  do_something
  and_so_on
end while
  something == nice and
  anotherthing == bad
```

**BUT in this case it will execute once before checking the condition**

You can kind of reverse it and it will work:

```
while
  something == nice and
  anotherthing == bad
  begin
    do_something
    and_so_on
  end 
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @TheShalit. After the comment from Cary i realized, that i missed to point out that i'm searching for a more consistent way to write multiline-statements in general, some kind of design-rule. I really appreciate your answer because of your interesting approach using an embedded block.

Comment: Glad I could help. I also agree with Cary, and work as he does.